# how to change td background color after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display message or any kind of notification to the user like change green background color after click or message like "you click successfully". My website image screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
                $url=$res['url'];
                $id=$res['id'];
            ?>
            <a href="out.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" onfocus="curTab">
                <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $res['image']; ?>" id="click"style="width:200px;height:75px;" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Javascript/jQuery for client side notifications.

jQuery solution:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <?php
            $url=$res['url'];
            $id=$res['id'];
        ?>
        <a href="out.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" onfocus="curTab">
            <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $res['image']; ?>" id="click" style="width:200px;height:75px;" class="myImgClass" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
$(".myImgClass").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background-color","green");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ron answer is right. And if you want to use the `onclick` attribute like you do (it is not used in Ron's answer), you'd do:

In the html: `onclick=myFunction(this)`

In the js:

```
function myFunction(elt) {
  $(elt).parent().css("background-color","green");
}
```